# UNION JOIN and MS-ACCESS

Tags: ms-access

REALLY CONFUSING IS, THAT IT WORKS UNDER JET, BUT NOT WORKING UNDER ACCESS....

How to do inner join WITH union

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM
(SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table1
JOIN table3 ON table1.id=table3.id
UNION ALL
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2 
JOIN table4 ON table2.id=table4.id) 
WHERE field3=1
```

the result:

> 3131 --"syntax error in FROM clause"

I reduced it into:

```
SELECT field1 FROM
(SELECT field1, field3 FROM table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT field1, field3 FROM table2)
WHERE field3=1
```

but still not working

even this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT field1 FROM table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT field1 FROM table2)
```

doesn't work

`SELECT field1 FROM table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT field1 FROM table2` - WORKS....

Comment: What do you mean by "works in Jet but not in Access"? Are you using ODBC or OLEDB or DAO from outside Access? The reason it's important is that lots of things change in the syntax of the SQL if you use a different interface to access the data (wild cards, derived-table syntax, reserved words, etc.).

Comment: it means exactly what i wrote. When I use "Access Console" - the same code responds with syntax error. When I use ODBC - the same code works.

Comment: What do you mean "Access Console"? Do you mean when you open the database in Access? Certainly ODBC is going to be a different environment and has completely different rules for execution of SQL. Where do you want it to work? ODBC or inside Access? If both, then you may have to have conditional construction of your SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Field3 in your query

```
SELECT t.field1, t.field2 
FROM (
    SELECT field1, field2, Field3
    FROM table1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table2
) as t
WHERE t.field3=1
```

BAsed on your edit with the new query you need the following:

```
SELECT X.field1, X.field2 
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id=t3.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.field1, t2.field2, t2.field3 
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t2.id=t4.id

) as x
WHERE x.field3=1
```

Comment: Worked for me, I tested it in Access 2003. What happens if you remove the where clause?

Comment: Obviously, I am missing something in what you want.  Based on your first post with the query, the answer I provided above works.

Comment: I updated my code with a JOIN and UNION that is working in Access.

Answer (score 0):

I have found in the past that I needed to parenthesise the 2 sides of the UNION - try the following:

```
SELECT X.field1, X.field2 
FROM
(
   (SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3 
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t1.id=t3.id)

    UNION ALL

   (SELECT t2.field1, t2.field2, t2.field3 
    FROM table2 t2
    INNER JOIN table4 t4 ON t2.id=t4.id)

) as x
WHERE x.field3=1
```